# sqlplus - turn off output (interactive)

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

In Oracle SQL*Plus, how can the output (to the terminal) be turned off?

This is for interactive mode, not running a script.

Example:

```
SELECT 1 from dual;
-- don't want to see the resulting row(s) !

var c refcursor
exec some_procedure(:c);
print
-- don't want to see the resulting row(s) variable C !
```

Primarily looking for solution on Windows, Oracle DB version 11.2.

Comment: Why would you query or print in the first place in an interactive session if you don't want to see the output?

Comment: Maybe I'm interested in just a part of the output. Or in the side effects. Or timing. Or... ;)

Answer (score 1):

[`set autotrace traceonly`](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQPUG/ch_twelve040.htm#SQPUG066) The query still runs. The results are sent to the client, but are not displayed. The plan and statistics are displayed however. The statistics requires access to certain `v$` views. To run without the statistics, `set autotrace traceonly explain`.

Answer (score 0):

You can't, really; the options that might help (like [`set termout off`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_eight.htm#sthref964), which you're presumably already familiar with) only apply when running a script.

I'm not sure it really makes sense for the `print` command, but if you really want to run a query without seeing the output could just put it in a PL/SQL block:

```
SQL> set feedback off
SQL> set timing on
  2  begin
  3    for r in (select 1 from dual) loop
  4      null;
  5    end loop;
  6  end;
  7  /

Elapsed: 00:00:00.00

SQL>
```

The `null;` is needed because you have to do something inside the loop. The compiler doesn't optimize it out - it does still execute the query and retrieve the results, at least as far as I can tell; a slightly more useful query like `select table_name from all_tables` takes non-zero time - 1.45 seconds on my system.

You could loop over a ref cursor result too I suppose, if you wanted to time the equivalent of the `print` fetches:

```
SQL> var c refcursor
  2  begin
  3    open :c for select table_name from all_tables;
  4  end;
  5  /

Elapsed: 00:00:00.17

SQL> declare
  2    t all_tables.table_name%type;
  3  begin
  4    loop
  5      fetch :c into t;
  6      exit when :c%notfound;
  7    end loop;
  8    close :c;
  9  end;
 10  /

Elapsed: 00:00:00.10
```

Answer (score 0):

I went with a script like this (in a file that I execute via @):

```
var c refcursor
set timi on
exec proc1(:c);
set feedback off
set timi off
exec DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(' before PRINT ' || systimestamp);
set termout off
print
set termout on
exec DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(' after PRINT  ' || systimestamp);
set feedback on
set timi on
rollback;
exit
```

*Set termout off* also suppresses the timing output, so I added the PUT_LINEs (could have used a *select systimestamp from dual* too).
I guess there is no short and elegant solution.